# M_SQRT1_2 isn't defined in OpenCL

Tags: xcode, opencl

I'm trying to compile the following in Xcode:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

double normcdf(double x) {
    return 0.5 * erfc(-x * M_SQRT1_2);
}
```

but I get the error: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'M_SQRT1_2'`

How can I use the constant `M_SQRT1_2`?

Comment: Seems like your compiler has a bug, since it is clearly defined in the CL 1.0 spec. https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mathConstants.html I would recomend you just define another constant yourself as a workaround  `#define SQRT1_2 0.707106781`

Comment: You can always use [math header](http://www.lemoda.net/c/maths-constants/).